# faye-websocket-rails and heroku dinamics chats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, faye

i create this chat https://intense-depths-60434.herokuapp.com/
with ruby on rails and im follow this guide: [heroku ruby websocket](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-websockets). 
all i want to do is to create chats between a x number of user but separated from the other "chats":
https://intense-depths-60434.herokuapp.com/room2

this is my middleware code:

module ChatDemo

```
      class ChatBackend
        KEEPALIVE_TIME = 15 # in seconds

        def initialize(app)
          @app     = app
          @clients = []
          @clientNames = []
        end

         def call(env)
            if Faye::WebSocket.websocket?(env)
                ws = Faye::WebSocket.new(env, nil, {ping: KEEPALIVE_TIME })

                ws.on :open do |event|
                  p [:open, ws.object_id]
                  @clients << ws
                end

                ws.on :message do |event|
                  p [:message, event.data]
                  @clients.each {|client| client.send(event.data) }
                end

                ws.on :close do |event|
                  p [:close, ws.object_id, event.code, event.reason]
                  @clients.delete(ws)
                  ws = nil
                end

                # WebSockets logic goes here

                # Return async Rack response
                ws.rack_response
            else
             @app.call(env)
            end
        end

      end

     end
```

this is my method code:

```
class ChatsController < ApplicationController

   def room
   end

   def room2
   end

end
```

and this is my js code:

```
    var scheme   = "wss://";
    var uri      = scheme + window.document.location.host+ "/";
    var ws       = new WebSocket(uri);

    ws.onmessage = function(message) {
      var data = JSON.parse(message.data);
      $("#chat-text").append("<div class='panel panel-default'><div class='panel-heading'>" + data.handle + "</div><div class='panel-body'>" + data.text + "</div></div>");
      $("#chat-text").stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $('#chat-text')[0].scrollHeight
      }, 800);
    };

    $("#input-form").submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var handle = $("#input-handle")[0].value;
      var text   = $("#input-text")[0].value;
      ws.send(JSON.stringify({ handle: handle, text: text }));
      $("#input-text")[0].value = "";
    });
```